# Calling $this->model->create() crashes in controller in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, model, crash, models

I am having a problem using the create() method in the cakephp. I have the following code and when I run it in debug it just resumes the program when I try to step through it after the create line.

```
$this->CompanyDeviceQuestionConcern->create();
$this->CompanyDeviceQuestionConcern->set('source_company_id', $company_id);
$this->CompanyDeviceQuestionConcern->set('user_id', $user['id']);
$this->CompanyDeviceQuestionConcern->set('create_date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$this->CompanyDeviceQuestionConcern->set('modified_date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Does anyone know why it crashes when I run the first line?

Comment: Define "crashes". What error do you get? What happens?

Comment: "when I run it in debug it just resumes the program when I try to step through it after the create line." There is no error, which is what makes it so hard to debug.

Comment: Why wouldn't it resume after `create()`?  create() just resets the model.  Call `->save()` after all the `set()` calls and it'll save to the DB.

Comment: Enable debug in core.php by setting it to 2 to see errors. Read the book.cakephp.org about the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the silly mistake. I forgot to include the model in $uses variable in the class at the top. It is rather inconvenient that it doesn't show any type of error however.
Here is what I added to fix it.

```
class ReviewsController extends AppController {
    var $uses = array('Question', 'CompanyTemplateGroupQuestionConcern');
```

Also if anyone wants any more information on how to uses works you can look here
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure but i think your database refuses the create action because of limitations of some fields(like `NOT NULL`).

There is a workaround for this:

```
$newData = array(
    'id' => NULL,
    'source_company_id' => $company_id,
    'user_id' => $user['id'],
    'create_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'modified_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);

$this->CompanyDeviceQuestionConcern->save($newData);
```